# Installing Keras broke Conda virtual environment (Windows 10)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, virtualenv

I was trying to install Keras on my python 3.7 environment then I noticed that neither tensorflow nor keras supports python 3.7, they support 3.6 
Then I created a new virtual environment with python 3.6 using conda/anaconda.
I was able to activate this virtual environment by entering
`activate deeplearning` in the cmd and then type `python` to enter python shell.
I installed Keras and its dependencies using `conda install -c conda-forge keras` , it seemed okay I entered the python shell imported keras and other libraries tinkered around with the libraries, they were working as intended. 
I closed down the window to try again if i can open up the virtual environment again manually myself.
 Typed `activate deeplearning`, and then I ran into this problem(
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc79q.jpg)
)
I only typed the `activate deeplearning` part on the cmd screenshot.

The problem here is that I can not enter the virtual environment, I get this commands? on the cmd and then it shuts itself down. I can not enter the virtual environment therefore preventing me from installing new libraries. But I can enter the python shell of this environment from where it is installed.
 However there is not a .bat file in the folder so I can not activate the virtual environment from there as well.

I do not know what to do, I would really appreciate it if someone could help, thanks in advance.

Comment: could you explain what is "this problem" ? we have a screenshot with a bunch of commands, but no "problem". Also, change from screenshot to actual text for indexing/other users that might look into the same issue.

Comment: The problem here is that I can not enter the virtual environment, I get this commands? on the cmd and then it shuts itself down. I can not activate the virtual environment therefore preventing me from installing new libraries. But I can enter the python shell of this environment from where it is installed.
However there is not a .bat file in the folder so I can not activate the virtual environment from there as well.

Comment: Btw the image is still there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the scripts for activating keras are exiting prematurely. One of the reasons can be that the environment is not set in python 3.6.

Try creating a virtual environment with command:

> conda create --name deeplearning python=3.6

And then you can follow instructions from:
http://inmachineswetrust.com/posts/deep-learning-setup/

Note: While installing keras use command:

> conda install keras

Comment: The first environment's python was not python 3.6 but the second ones python is 3.6, still it is not working having the same error(exiting prematurely)

Comment: Just to confirm - Did you try all of the above steps?

>conda create --name deeplearning python=3.6
>activate deeplearning
>conda install ipython
>conda install jupyter
>conda install pandas
>conda install scipy
>conda install seaborn
>conda install scikit-learn
>conda install keras

I face a similar issue recently, but after doing above steps I was able to install & use keras. You would also require  Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (you may also check whether it is installed). If this doesn't work, I guess you will have to debug the scripts.

Comment: I just have been able to use keras and tensorflow now. Created virtual environment of python 3.6 using anaconda, installed some packages using `conda install <package_name> `. And then installed tensorflow and keras using `pip install tensorflow` `pip install keras`  I think `conda install tensorflow` and `conda install keras` breaks these 2 packages somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on Python 2.7 by removing via Anaconda Navigator the item that goes by the name vs2008_win-32, that fixed my environment.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, the error was caused by another activation script, probably installed at the same time. To confirm that this is the case for you, look into the batch file generated dynamically at startup. To find out its name, change `_conda_activate.bat` as so:

```
...

:FIXUP43
@FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('@CALL "%CONDA_EXE%" shell.cmd.exe %*') DO @SET "_TEMP_SCRIPT_PATH=%%i"
@IF "%_TEMP_SCRIPT_PATH%"=="" @EXIT /B 1
@IF NOT "%CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER%" == "" @CALL SET "PROMPT=%%PROMPT:%CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER%=%_empty_not_set_%%%"

:: Add these lines:
set _TEMP_SCRIPT_PATH
pause

@CALL "%_TEMP_SCRIPT_PATH%"
...
```

In the temp script comment out the invocation of other scripts
until you find the culprit. For me it was something to do with vs2015.

```
@SET "PYTHONIOENCODING=1252"
@CALL "C:\Users\x030551\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\etc\conda\activate.d\keras_activate.bat"
:: @CALL "C:\Users\x030551\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\etc\conda\activate.d\vs2015_compiler_vars.bat"
```

Once I had this information, Google pointed me to [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23310). The solution to that depends too much on your environment to post here.